# Flow Generic type <T> 'incompatible with object type'

Tags: javascript, generics, flowtype

Here is a simplified example for the Flow errors i'm getting when trying to annotate with generics:

```
// @flow

function component<T>(state: T) {
    let model = deepFreeze(state);
    //        ^ Cannot call `deepFreeze` with `state` bound to `o` 
    //          because `T` [1] is incompatible with object type [2].

    return {
        update: (state: T) => {
        // etc.
        }
    };
}

function deepFreeze(o: Object) {
    Object.freeze(o);
    // etc.
    return o;
}
```

It seems to me that `<T>` should simply track the type, whatever it is.

In this example i've used the least specific type I could find, about which the docs say: "if you need to opt-out of the type checker, and don’t want to go all the way to any, you can instead use Object".

So how is it possible to use polymorphic types, when they inevitably end up being used in a more specific way elsewhere?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Narrowing the Generic type removes the errors:

```
function component<T: {}>(state: T) {
    ...
}
```

From the [docs](https://flow.org/en/docs/types/generics/#toc-adding-types-to-generics):

...*generics have an “unknown” type. You’re not allowed to use a generic as if it were a specific type.*
*You could add a type to your generic... This way you can keep the behavior of generics while only allowing certain types to be used.*